# Compiler Error when Compiling GCC 5.3.0 (-Lyes/lib and -Iyes/include)

Tags: gcc, configure

When attempting to compile GNU GCC 5.3.0 I encounter the following error when it tries to build `libjavamath.la`.

```
/bin/bash ../../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link /home/borish/Downloads/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/borish/Downloads/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -W -Wall -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-long-long  -Iyes/include -g -O2 -module -version-info 0:0:0 -no-undefined -Lyes/lib -lgmp -avoid-version  -o libjavamath.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/../lib64/gcj-5.3.0-16 gnu_java_math_GMP.lo ../../../native/jni/classpath/jcl.lo 
../../../libtool: line 5209: cd: yes/lib: No such file or directory
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `yes/lib'
Makefile:403: recipe for target 'libjavamath.la' failed
```

This is on a Debian 8.4 system with GCC 4.9.2-10 installed.  I believe I have satisfied all of the [prerequisites](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html), and [Google wasn't been much help](https://www.google.com/#q=GNU+GCC+5.3+%22libtool%3A+line+5209%3A+cd%3A+yes%2Flib%3A+No+such+file+or+directory%22).

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

I used the following for running the configuration script:

```
../gcc-5.3.0/configure --disable-multilib --with-mpc --with-isl --with-mpfr --with-gmp
```

Comment: `-Lyes/lib` looks weird to me. Obviously, the key to the question is in the `libtool` file. Where `yes/lib` comes from? Also, it's interesting how the `configure` command looks.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov It's referenced in several of the Makefiles, and appears commonly associated with the `libgmp`.

Comment: I'm trying again without all of the `--with-XXX` switches, just including the `--disable-multilib` and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't run "configure" correctly.  For example:

> https://software.ecmwf.int/issues/browse/SUP-676
>
> OK, I see a problem already, the "--with-jasper" option must point the
>   to the prefix of the "jasper" installation, for example
>
> ```
> $./configure --with-jasper=/usr/local/jasper --with-png-support.
> ```
>
> Otherwise the value "yes" is set as prefix..

For example, if you look here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html

you'll see that a flag like `‘--with-headers=directory’` *REQUIRES YOU TO ENTER A DIRECTORY PATH*.  I suspect the same thing is happening with your "-with-mpc" etc.

SUGGESTION: clean your build directory, and (carefully!) re-run `./configure`.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit appears to be the `--with-gmp`, `--with-mpc` and `--with-mpfr` switches when initiating the `configure` script.  I suspect since `libgmp` is a prerequisite for `libmpc` and `libmpfr`, a <strike>bug</strike> feature in the `configure` script will include the offending `-I` and `-L` directives.  Inclusion of any of them will result in the following in the root Makefile

```
HOST_GMPLIBS = -Lyes/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp
HOST_GMPINC = -Iyes/include
```

I haven't confirmed this to be the case in any of the other Makefiles, but I suspect something similar is going on elsewhere which is what I ran into when it attempted to building `libjavamath.la`.

The work around is to omit those switches from the configure invocation.  They should be included in any event since the `configure` script will fail if they aren't present on the host.

Comment: @paulsm4 No; there is no such directory anywhere on the host.  There is a file called `/usr/bin/yes` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) but no folders.  It looks like the configure script inserted a `yes` based on the switches.

Comment: Yup.  Here's an example of how "configure" might insert "yes" as a prefix if you fail to supply an argument, or fat-finger something: https://software.ecmwf.int/issues/browse/SUP-676.  SUGGESTION: clean *EVERYTHING*, then re-run ./configure".

Comment: @paulsm4 Yup, that's what I'm doing.